# How can i make the Javascript work for a Carousel by using bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a carousel to display pictures for a restaurant's page. I followed a bootstrap tutorial video to code it.

Everythings seems to be working but the carousel refuses to move so i thought it might be a problem with the javascript. However, i cant find whats the problem. I already tried : removing the "5000" property but it did nothing.

I then tried to run the code in the stak snippet tool and i told me that jquery was needed. Which is weird since theres a call for Jquery at the end of the code.

Many thanks for the help !

Bastien

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> bootstrap exercises </title>
    <!latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>



<html>


<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- data-ride calls the javascript, via bootstrap needed for the carousel to be animated -->
                    <div data-ride="carousel" id="my-slider" class="carousel slide"   data-keyboard="false" data-interval="1500"   >


                        <!-- indicators -->

                            <ul class="carousel-indicators">

                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> 0</li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="3"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="5"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="6"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="7"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="8"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="9"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="10"> </li>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- wrapper for slides-->

                            <div class="carousel-inner " >

                                <div class="carousel-item active">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/12/44/burgers-1839090__340.jpg" alt=" juicy flamed grill">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our juicy flamed grill burger </p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/24/15/14/parsley-4876518__340.jpg" alt="do not feel guilty pasta plate ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our pasta plate </p>

                                    </div>



                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/19/01/02/avocado-895361__340.jpg" alt=" sweet potatoes fries">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Sweet potatoes fries with 2 sauces and spices </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/17/12/43/steak-3544070__340.jpg" alt="Irish grilled steak with 5% only fat ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our famous irish steak </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/13/14/23/spaghetti-bolognese-4546233__340.jpg ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Spaghetti bolognese with 0% fat beef and fresh tomatoes/mushrooms </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"  src=" https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/05/20/07/abstract-1238657__340.jpg" alt="Entry : tuna peaches, Main course : celtic lamb, Desert : proteined bananas ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Entry : tuna peaches, Main course : celtic lamb, Desert : proteined bananas </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/06/17/45/salmon-1312372__340.jpg" alt=" scottish salmone">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Entry : 10g of caviar layed on a rice leaf, Main course : rare piece of Salmone from Scotland, Desert : top quality belgian chocolate </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/07/08/50/kobe-3136608__340.jpg" alt="Piece of Wagyu beef : 150g ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Piece of Wagyu beef : 150g </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/01/22/08/buffet-1562290__340.jpg" alt=" assiette mixte">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> assiette mixte : vegetables </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cold-smoked-meat-platter-snacks-set-picture-id1159740379?b=1&k=6&m=1159740379&s=170667a&w=0&h=JsuWStBo_Alh2g0DLjLpX4sq1DiFL9znEV1mfrsbyeA=" alt=" mix viande">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> assiette mixte : viande</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>


                            </div>



                            <!-- next and prev buttons -->


                            <a class= "carousel-control-prev" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>

                            <a class=" carousel-control-next" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>


                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>



    <!-- Javascript files linked at the bottom of the page-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include jquery **before**(must be) js bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> bootstrap exercises </title>
    <!latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>



<html>


<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- data-ride calls the javascript, via bootstrap needed for the carousel to be animated -->
                    <div data-ride="carousel" id="my-slider" class="carousel slide"   data-keyboard="false" data-interval="1500"   >


                        <!-- indicators -->

                            <ul class="carousel-indicators">

                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> 0</li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="2"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="3"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="5"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="6"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="7"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="8"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="9"> </li>
                                <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="10"> </li>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- wrapper for slides-->

                            <div class="carousel-inner " >

                                <div class="carousel-item active">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/19/12/44/burgers-1839090__340.jpg" alt=" juicy flamed grill">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our juicy flamed grill burger </p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/24/15/14/parsley-4876518__340.jpg" alt="do not feel guilty pasta plate ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our pasta plate </p>

                                    </div>



                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/08/19/01/02/avocado-895361__340.jpg" alt=" sweet potatoes fries">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Sweet potatoes fries with 2 sauces and spices </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/17/12/43/steak-3544070__340.jpg" alt="Irish grilled steak with 5% only fat ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Here a picture of our famous irish steak </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/13/14/23/spaghetti-bolognese-4546233__340.jpg ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Spaghetti bolognese with 0% fat beef and fresh tomatoes/mushrooms </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"  src=" https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/05/20/07/abstract-1238657__340.jpg" alt="Entry : tuna peaches, Main course : celtic lamb, Desert : proteined bananas ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Entry : tuna peaches, Main course : celtic lamb, Desert : proteined bananas </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/06/17/45/salmon-1312372__340.jpg" alt=" scottish salmone">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> Entry : 10g of caviar layed on a rice leaf, Main course : rare piece of Salmone from Scotland, Desert : top quality belgian chocolate </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">


                                    <img class ="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/07/08/50/kobe-3136608__340.jpg" alt="Piece of Wagyu beef : 150g ">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p>Piece of Wagyu beef : 150g </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>



                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100"src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/01/22/08/buffet-1562290__340.jpg" alt=" assiette mixte">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> assiette mixte : vegetables </p>

                                    </div>


                                </div>


                                <div class="carousel-item">

                                    <img class ="d-block w-100" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cold-smoked-meat-platter-snacks-set-picture-id1159740379?b=1&k=6&m=1159740379&s=170667a&w=0&h=JsuWStBo_Alh2g0DLjLpX4sq1DiFL9znEV1mfrsbyeA=" alt=" mix viande">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">

                                        <p> assiette mixte : viande</p>

                                    </div>

                                </div>


                            </div>



                            <!-- next and prev buttons -->


                            <a class= "carousel-control-prev" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>

                            <a class=" carousel-control-next" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>


                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Javascript files linked at the bottom of the page-->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







</body>

</html>
```